# Is it possible to built an extension which has a hotkey set that activates an extension panel and jumps to a field?

Tags: sdk, panel, after-effects

I am working on an extension for after effects and I am searching for a way to set a hotkey that will "activate" my docked extension panel and then jump to an entryfield within the panel.

...

That might sound easy, but actually I talked to a lot of developers and all of them said it is impossible. It would only work for a script with a non dockable UI panel. Is that true? Isn´t there any workaround for this seamingly easy task?

Thanks!

Sascha